# Connect By in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, connect-by

I have this select statement to display 20 records of time in Oracle

```
          SELECT  SYSDATE  +   (1 - LEVEL)/ 24 / 3600 * 600 ten_sec
                                                     FROM DUAL
                                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
```

this displays current time and 19 more records with 10 minutes prior like

10:35:03

10:25:03

10:15:03...

How do i do same in Mysql?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 600` or something like the following to work around:

```
SELECT dt 
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) AS dt 
  UNION
  SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AS dt
  UNION 
  SELECT NOW() AS dt
  ) a
```

You want to go ahead and subtract with other subqueries ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i get this  error    :                         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY 
round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Now()) / 600)

Comment: I tried using "from dual". Still showing same error.

Comment: @Shanna take a look at the updated answer I proposes a workaround that you give in MySQL the same result you have in Oracle ...